# Weblogic JMS Client - Creating connection from connection factory unresponsive

Tags: jms, weblogic12c

I've been able to successfully create a weblogic jms client, and I've been able to run it successfully on LAPTOP A, sending messages to my jms queue configured on my company's server: SERVER A.

Now, the issue I'm having is, when I run the jms client on another laptop, LAPTOP B, the client stops at the point where it's trying to create a connection from the connection factory:

```
String queueConnectionFactory = "jms/thefactory"
QueueConnectionFactory qconFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(queueConnectionFactory);
QueueConnection qcon = qconFactory.createQueueConnection(); //application freezes here!
```

While this is happening, when I go back to LAPTOP A and run the jms client, the same thing happens.

I proceed to terminate the client apps on both laptops, and a couple minutes later, this comes up on the weblogic's server log:

```
java.io.EOFException: Attempt to send message on closed socket.
java.rmi.MarshalException: IOException while sending; nested exception is:
        java.io.EOFException: Attempt to send message on closed socket
        at weblogic.iiop.EndPointImpl.send(EndPointImpl.java:1155)
        at weblogic.iiop.OutboundResponseImpl.sendThrowable(OutboundResponseImpl.java:221)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleThrowable(BasicServerRef.java:866)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.postInvoke(BasicServerRef.java:762)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:542)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
Caused By: java.io.EOFException: Attempt to send message on closed socket
        at weblogic.iiop.MuxableSocketIIOP.send(MuxableSocketIIOP.java:469)
        at weblogic.protocol.AsyncMessageSenderImpl.sendOutMsg(AsyncMessageSenderImpl.java:90)
        at weblogic.protocol.AsyncMessageSenderImpl.send(AsyncMessageSenderImpl.java:46)
        at weblogic.iiop.MuxableSocketIIOP$IIOPConnection.send(MuxableSocketIIOP.java:582)
        at weblogic.iiop.EndPointImpl.send(EndPointImpl.java:1148)
        at weblogic.iiop.OutboundResponseImpl.sendThrowable(OutboundResponseImpl.java:221)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleThrowable(BasicServerRef.java:866)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.postInvoke(BasicServerRef.java:762)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicServerRef.handleRequest(BasicServerRef.java:542)
        at weblogic.rmi.internal.wls.WLSExecuteRequest.run(WLSExecuteRequest.java:118)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

And after a while, I'm able to run the jms client from LAPTOP A. But the instant I try again from LAPTOP B, the whole issue I just described begins.

Both laptops can ping the server and telnet into the server's port. In fact, both connect the JMS server fine. It's the factory connection creation that brings out this strange issue.

I don't understand what's going on. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out a long time ago but forgot to put up the answer.

The issue was the weblogic jars I was using. You see, one of the laptop was a Windows system and the other was a Linux system, and for some weird reason, the weblogic jars you use for the client differs depending on its host operating system.

The client was going to run on Windows, so I used these jars: wlclient.jar and wljmsclient.jar.